# Which ring in 2-chain is compatible with a compact 2d manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In algebraic topology, a $k$-chain is a formal linear combination of the $k$-cells in a cell complex, and linear combination is based on some ring $R$. Does the manifold itself impact the selection of the ring $R$?

A special case is that: for a non-orientable manifold $M$, such as a Klein bottle, we consider

$$K = \sum_i \sigma_i$$

i.e. on each of its cells $\sigma_i$, we assign $1$ to it.

And then we applying boundary operator on $K$, we have:

$$\partial_2 K = \sum_i \partial_2\sigma_i$$

since each boundary $\partial_2\sigma_i$ is orientable, it seems to be true, $\partial_2 K$ is orientable? But this is a contradictory with the non-oriental nature of $M$?

We may use another ring other than $\mathbb Z$ to escape from the contradictory, if the above understanding is not wrong.

---

Update after discussion with @WSL, and thank for him.

My confusion is base on this proposition: finite sum of positive-oriented small pieces is still positive-oriented.

So if we cut a hole $\sigma_0$ on $M$ to get $M^\prime$, then on one hand we have:

$$\partial M^\prime = -\partial \sigma_0$$

On the other hand, $\sigma_0$ is only the first piece of all $\sigma_i$, if the above in-question proposition hold, we may say finite sum of positive-oriented small pieces $\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$ is still positive-oriented. But after we assigned positive-orientation on all of $\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$, we also assigned a direction on each edge of $\sigma_0$ naturally, which may give a positive-orientation of $\sigma_0$ also. This part is in question?

Comment: What is a ``constant unit field''?

Comment: Thanks, I had changed the question a little bit on that part.

Comment: Okay, I'm still not sure what the confusion is. if $\partial_2$ is the standard boundary map, the n $\partial_2K=0$ since $K$ is closed.

Comment: I don't know what that means. When you cut a closed surface into two components $M = M'\sqcup M''$, the boundaries need to be coherently oriented (eg: $\partial M' = -\partial M''$). Either way, the Klein bottle is a closed surface, so its boundary is empty.

Comment: If we cut a hole on $\sigma_0$ to get $M\prime$ , $\partial M\prime$ as a finite sum of  orientable boundary, it seems the result sum is orientable, i.e. $\partial M\prime = \partial \sigma_0$, and we get $\partial \sigma_0 = - \partial \sigma_0$

Comment: sorry for confusion, I think what you said is the right part of $\partial \sigma_0 = - \partial \sigma_0$, but the left part is from a finite sum of orientable boundary should be the same orientation as all the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the coefficients of homology are from a *commutative ring*, not necessarily a field (most commonly we consider $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, which is not a field because only $1$ and $-1$ have multiplicative inverses).

For the Klein bottle $K$ there is a CW structure consisting of one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells, say $a$ and $b$, and one $2$-cell $e$ attached in a way so that its boundary goes to $abab^{-1}$ (to see this consider [the fundamental polygonal of the Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#Construction)). In the cellular chain complex we have $\partial_2(e) = a + b + a - b = 2a$, so it is not a cycle with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients and in particular $H_2(K;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. However, with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients this chain *is* a cycle and $H_2(K;\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.

The relevant results here are that if $M$ is a closed (i.e. compact and without boundary) and connected manifold of dimension $n$ then $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ if $M$ is orientable and $0$ otherwise, and that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ regardless of orientability. Neither of these results are completely elementary, but you will typically see them in an algebraic topology course covering homology theory; one of the essential ideas is that if a manifold is non-orientable then the boundary of its "fundamental class" is a multiple of two. It's important to note that neither coefficient ring is necessarily more "correct" than the other, they just give two different pieces of information.

Comment: Thank William, since I just start to learn this part, I need time to absorb all the information of your answer, after I fully understand that I will give an 'accept'.